# this.$el.on Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

What is the meaning of `this.$el.on(App.fileUploadCallbacks())` in Marionette?

I know that App.fileUploadCallbacks() is a function that has been defined elsewhere in the code, but I'm not used to seeing the `.on` function used without an event name + a function to call when that event is triggered.

```
App.fileUploadCallbacks = function() {
  return {
    fileuploadadd: function(evt, data) {
      data.files[0].timestamp = +(new Date);
      return data.files[0].originalFile = data.files[0];
    },
    fileuploadprogress: function(evt, data) {
      return App.vent.trigger("file:progress", data);
    },
    fileuploadprocessdone: function(evt, data) {
      return App.vent.trigger('file:dropped', data, $(this));
    },
    fileuploadprocessfail: function(evt, data) {
      return console.w;
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just binding events to callback functions. Your method returns a hash of event names and the corresponding callbacks to invoke when those events are raised.

Answer (score 0):

App.fileUploadCallbacks returns an object with event names as keys and handler functions as values. Here's why it works:

`View.$el` is a jQuery object.

`jQuery.on` can take an object in the format `{ eventType: handlerFunction }` (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)).

`App.fileUploadCallbacks` returns an object in this format, so following blocks of code are equivalent:

**Calling a method that returns an object in the expected format:**

```
 this.$el.on(App.fileUploadCallbacks())
```

**Providing an object literal:**

```
this.$el.on({
  fileuploadadd: function(evt, data) {
    data.files[0].timestamp = +(new Date);
    return data.files[0].originalFile = data.files[0];
  },
  fileuploadprogress: function(evt, data) {
    return App.vent.trigger("file:progress", data);
  },
  fileuploadprocessdone: function(evt, data) {
    return App.vent.trigger('file:dropped', data, $(this));
  },
  fileuploadprocessfail: function(evt, data) {
    return console.w;
  }
});
```

**Registering individual event handlers**:

```
this.$el.on("fileuploadadd", function(evt, data) {
  data.files[0].timestamp = +(new Date);
  return data.files[0].originalFile = data.files[0];
});

this.$el.on("fileuploadprogress", function(evt, data) {
  return App.vent.trigger("file:progress", data);
});

this.$el.on("fileuploadprocessdone", function(evt, data) {
  return App.vent.trigger('file:dropped', data, $(this));
});

this.$el.on("fileuploadprocessfail", function(evt, data) {
    return console.w;
});
```

Note that the event names are now strings, not object keys, so they need to be quoted.